# Find solution to sort the array which scans the array once

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

```
package recursion;
public class QuickSort {

public static void quickSort(int[] input,int beginIndex,int endIndex)
{
    if(beginIndex>=endIndex)
    {
        return;
    }

    int pivotIndex = partition(input,beginIndex,endIndex);

    quickSort(input, beginIndex, pivotIndex-1);

    quickSort(input, pivotIndex+1, endIndex);
}

public static int partition(int[] input,int beginIndex,int endIndex)
{
    int count = 0;
    int pivotElement = input[beginIndex];
    for(int i = beginIndex+1;i<=endIndex;i++)
    {
        if(pivotElement >= input[i])
            count++;
    }

    int temp2 = beginIndex;


    int temp = pivotElement;
    input[beginIndex] = input[count+beginIndex];
    input[count+beginIndex] = temp;

    while(beginIndex < endIndex)
    {
        if(input[beginIndex] <= pivotElement)
        {

            beginIndex++;
        }
        else if(input[endIndex]>pivotElement)
        {

            endIndex--;
        }

        else            
        {
            int temp3 = input[beginIndex];
            input[beginIndex] = input[endIndex];
            input[endIndex] = temp3;

        }
    }

    return temp2 + count;


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] n = {0,1,0,2,2,1,1,0};
    quickSort(n, 0, 7);

    for(int i = 0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(n[i]);
    }

}

}
```

Given an array containing only 0’s, 1’s and 2’s, I want to set my pivot element to be equal to 1 so that all the 0s comes before it and all the 2s comes after it
this way it will only scan the array once.
But I am not able to set my pivot element to be 1

So please help me in solving this!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Create an array of length 3. For each input add one to the corresponding index of the counting array. Finally, iterate the counting array and create an output array. Something like

```
public static int[] countingSort(int[] input) {
    int[] count = new int[3];
    for (int i : input) {
        count[i]++;
    }
    int pos = 0;
    int[] output = new int[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        for (int t = 0; t < count[i]; t++) {
            output[pos++] = i;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```